# Error at the list of arguments of a method

Tags: c++, methods, compiler-errors

Using [this thread as help](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/209784/) I want to calculate the distance between two vectors. So my method to do this will be:

```
template <typename T>
double  vectors_distance(vector<double> vec1, vector<double> vec2) {
    std::vector<double> aux;

    std::transform(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), vec2.begin(), std::back_inserter(aux), 
        [](double element1, double element2) {return pow((element1 - element2), 2); 
    });
    aux.shrink_to_fit();

    return  std::sqrt(std::accumulate(aux.begin(), aux.end(), 0.0));
}
```

In another method I create two `vector<double> numbers, numbers1` and fill them up with some values, like this:

```
stringstream ss(coordSynth);
        double num;
        while (ss >> num) {
            numbers.push_back(num);
            cout << typeid(numbers).name() << endl;
        }
```

**EDIT:**

As background knowledge: `coordSynth` is a string, which contains `doubles` as values (ie: "0.0, 45.3, 2.0"). For `number1` happens exactly the same (as for `number`).
Fine, now I'm calling `vectors_distance(numbers, numbers1);` and get the error `E0304 No instance of function template "vectors_distance" matches the argument list.`. But how? My method has exactly two parameters and I put in there also two vectors?

Comment: `vectors_distance` is a *function-template* whose arguments does not favor *function Template Argument Deduction*. Did you provide the explicit template argument `vectors_distance<T>(numbers, numbers2)`?. Besides, I see no use of the template there. Perhaps, [**this**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe8387b63f6a1f90) is what you want?

Comment: You do not supply the template argument `T` and it can't be deduced. In fact it appears unused.

Comment: 1) _and get the error E0304_ **Copy-paste** the error message. We don't memorize error codes (even if we were - error codes are implementation dependent, hence - would change from compiler to compiler). 2) `T` can never be deduced for your function, since you don't provide it explicitly, and your arguments don't depend on it.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I would to, but as I am German the error message is in german.

Comment: You should be aware that [`std::vector::shrink_to_fit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) is a non-binding request. In most implementation it will reduce capacity to a value it would naturally increase to through repeated `push_back`. In this use case, these implementations would never do anything, since `aux` is already as that capacity. Instead, consider using [`std::vector::reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) before inserting into it.

Comment: @Unnamed Then translate it to English. Read point 2.

Comment: Better still, give us the German, along with a translation of the human readable parts. We too can use Google Translate.

Comment: I think @Unnamed means something like that https://www.quantnet.com/threads/compile-time-error-from-implementing-templates.29120/

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius did it, see edit im my question. For the second point: okay, how can I fix it?

Comment: @Unnamed No. That's not how templates work. You aren't using it for anything, `std::accumulate` deduces it's own template arguments. Even if you supplied the argument yourself, the only type you could correctly pass is `double`.

Comment: @Unnamed What does the book, you are learning C++ from, tells you on the topic on templates? Either use generic type, in the function, instead of `double`, or drop the template entirely, if the only type, the function makes sense on is `double`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you have specified the function as a template, but neither of the function arguments are related to the template argument.

If you want the function to only work for `std::vector<double>`, the function doesn't need to be a template.

```
double  vectors_distance(vector<double> vec1, vector<double> vec2)
{
     // same body you have
}
```

If you want the function to work for a `std::vector<T>` (assuming `T` is a type that can be supplied to `pow()`, etc)  then keep it as a template, and change `double` to `T` within the function.  For example;

```
template <typename T>
T vectors_distance(vector<T> vec1, vector<T> vec2)
{
      // same function body, but replace "double" by "T" everywhere
}
```

A couple of other comments.

Firstly, it is usually better to pass `std::vector` arguments by `const` reference, not by value.

Second, it is not necessary to build a temporary vector to hold intermediate results.  Simply use a better algorithm.  For example the non-template version might be written

```
double  vectors_distance(const vector<double> &vec1, const vector<double> &vec2)
{
     return std::sqrt(
              std::inner_product(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), vec2.begin(), 0.0,
                                 std::plus<double>(),
                                 [](double e1, double e2) {return (e1-e2)*(e1-e2);}
                                )
             );
}
```

Read the documentation for `std::inner_product()` to see what this does.

Comment: Your second advise does not return the same calculation as my method above.

Comment: Yeah, okay.   Wrote too fast.  Order of last two arguments was wrong.